# Create HTML Table Using ng-repeat from Array

Tags: angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

Can Someone help me to create the HTML table using the Angular JS ng-repeat. And I have the the array as below

```
cyclename = [cycle1,cycle2,cycle3]
passValue = [2,5,250]
```

Using these I wanted to generate the HTML Table as

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>cycle1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cycle2</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cycle3</td>
    <td>250</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have tried in Angular JS as below but didnot work

```
<table class="table">
    <tr ng-repeat="x in cyclename">
    <td>{{x}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in passValue">
    <td>{{x}}</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2]">
        <td>{{cyclename[i]}}</td>
        <td>{{passValue[i]}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

"Normal" solution by merging the values into objects like @sachila's answer.
In case you need help in changing the arrays into objects:

```
$scope.fullArr = cyclename.map(function(item, i) {
  return {
    cyclename: item,
    passValue: passValue[i]
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

modify you arrays into ine object array

```
fullArr = [{cyclename :'cycle1',passValue : '2' },{cyclename :'cycle2',passValue : '5' },{cyclename :'cycle3',passValue : '250' }]

 <table class="table">
    <tr ng-repeat="x in fullArr">
    <td>{{x.cyclename}}</td>
    <td>{{x.passValue}}</td>
    </tr> 
 </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplest one approach use the $scope and refer to below code

**Controller**:

```
 $scope.cyclename = ["cycle1","cycle2","cycle3"]
 $scope.passValue = [2,5,250]
```

**Template**

```
<table>
 <tr ng-repeat="x in cyclename">
   <td>{{x}}</td>
   <td>{{passValue[$index]}}</td>
 </tr>
```

Hope this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Dt0nDUpVrl1dvCv1ZgCQ?p=preview) will help you

Comment: Please check the required result html structure?

Comment: @Icycool Please let me know what is wrong with HTML structure?

Comment: your code is generating `<tr><td>x3</tr>x2` instead of `<tr><td>x2</tr>x3` as requested by OP

Comment: @Icycool Thanks.I updated the plunker with 2 type of table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Merge Two Arrays with key value pair and use ng-repeat

```
cyclename = [cycle1,cycle2,cycle3]
passValue = [2,5,250]

to 

mergerArr=[{
             key:cycle1,
             value:2
            },{
             key:cycle2,
             value:5
           }]
```

Html will be like below

```
<table class="table">
<tr ng-repeat="x in mergerArr">
<td>{{x.key}}</td>
<td>{{x.value}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```